# internal server error in ajax request php

Tags: php, ajax, internal-server-error

internal server error in ajax request my function work correctly in localhost but in cpanel return Error 500

```
var MainRoot = 'http://localhost/sjkala/admin/';
   function NumberToPersianWord(price_area,num)
{
    var price=document.getElementById(num).value;
    var finalprice =parseFloat(price.replace(/,/g, ''));
    if(finalprice > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:MainRoot+'NumberToPersianWord',
            type:"POST",
            data:'price='+finalprice,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#"+price_area).html(data);
            }
        });
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

and php code

```
public function NumberToPersianWord()
{
    $int=gmp_init(Request::get('price'));
    $price=gmp_strval($int);
    if(is_numeric($price))
    {
        if(strlen($price) > 1)
        {
            $final= substr($price, 0, -1);
            $final=$price;
        }else{
            $final=$price;
        }

        $num=new numToWord_Fa();
        print $num->numberToWords($final)." تومان ";
    }else{
        $bad=url('BadRequest');
        header('Location:'.$bad);
    }

}
```

in locahost work perfect but in cpanel return Error 500

Comment: Compare the modules/extensions installed by `php -i` from CLI or create a simple script doing `phpinfo()`. Also try to match Apache2/nginx configuration. Easiest way could be checking the logfiles for errors.

Comment: As Markus said , firstly kindly check if proper PHP version is installed on your server or not.

Comment: Start by checking the error logs, to find out what the actual cause of the error was.

Comment: Try after removing `http://localhost/` from `MainRoot `.

Comment: in error_log CPANEL ::  Call to undefined function gmp_init();    my PHPVERSION :::  5.6

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php

Comment: You should replace the domain name with http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line.

`var MainRoot = 'http://localhost/sjkala/admin/';`

Try replacing it with your domain name. Let's say your domain is example.com Try something like this.

`var MainRoot = 'http://example.com/sjkala/admin/';`

But this **sjkala/admin/ SHOULD REPLACE WITH CORRECT PATH**